# What is MOFA attestation in UAE

Tags: paperwork, india, education, uae

I want to attest my education documents to apply for professional visa in UAE. I have done my masters degree from India. What is the procedures to get MOFA stamp in UAE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Degree Certificate Attestation for UAE is one of the mandatory requirements to get an eligible work visa in UAE. This also is practiced in other GCC countries.

MOFA refers to [Ministry of Foreign Affairs](https://www.mofaic.gov.ae/en/), is the official body to attest or legalize documents for UAE.

The MOFA attestation UAE is the last step to get the degree certificate attested for UAE. Make sure the degree certificate is valid and awarded by the affiliated board from India to avoid any rejection in the process.

### Steps to get Indian certificate attested for UAE

1. First of all the degree certificate needs to be verified by the **Notary public**.
2. Once the document is verified by Notary, the document will be forwarded to **Home Department Mantralaya/SDM - Sub Division Magistrate**.
3. The next step in the process is to get the stamp from **Ministry of External Affairs - New Delhi**.
4. The next step is to get the Legalization from **UAE Embassy New Delhi, India**
5. The last step in the process is to attest the document from **The Ministry Of Foreign Affairs(MOFA)**, UAE

From my personal experience, the process takes very lengthy in order to send and receive the documents from various government bodies. I contacted the local [attestation services agent in dubai](https://www.attest.ae) to save my time during the attestation/visa process.

If you are doing MOFA attestation by yourself, its always better to check the MOFA website for latest updates as there may be chances of branch closure due to COVID-19.